# Ember.js: select state not saved in URL when reload page

Tags: select, ember.js, ember-data

There are select on the page for choosing country and it's need to save selected value in URL.
I declared query params in route-driven controllers.
It's all work! If country select is changed then url also changed.

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/releza

But if I reload page with some valid GET params then it params convert to 'undefined'.
For example, I try to load page

```
http://output.jsbin.com/releza#/?country=2
```

and it redirect to

```
http://output.jsbin.com/releza#/?country=undefined
```

Why?

```
# index.hbl
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{view "select" content=countries   
                  optionValuePath="content.id" 
                  optionLabelPath="content.name"  
                  value=country
                  prompt="Select a country"}}
</script>

# apps.js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

// ROUTES
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('countries', this.store.find('country'));
    }
});

// CONTROLLERS
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['country'],
    country: null,
});

// MODELS
App.Country = DS.Model.extend({  
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/countries",
  dataType: 'json',
  responseText: {
    "country": [
      {"id":1, "name":"Абхазия"},
      {"id":2, "name":"Австралия"},
      {"id":3, "name":"Австрия"},
      {"id":4,"name":"Азейбарджан"},
    ],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `setupController` to feed data into the controller. And you set the `counties` property to a promise returned by `store.find()`.

When the page loads, Ember does not wait for that promise to resolve. Thus, the select box appears with no entries, and the query params entry is considered non-existing and replaced by `undefined`.

To resolve the issue, use the route's `model` hook. Then Ember will wait for the promise to resolve before passing the word to the controller, and the select box will appear with its items preloaded.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/citomu/1/edit?html,js,output

Note that you're not experiencing the issue from your previous question because Ember Data internally converts record ids to strings.

Comment: And what if I need two models (and two select accordingly). For example, country and city. How can I represent city in this case?

Comment: I found answer for two models on one route
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521967/emberjs-how-to-load-multiple-models-on-the-same-route

Comment: The "beware" answer is pretty complicated. I showed you a simple solution with sideloading.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your answer.
it is just what I need http://jsbin.com/citomu/2/edit?html,js,output
Thank you so much!